# Write a list and strings in one row each in its own cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I have extracted four items (one list of strings and three strings) and I want to write all four items in a single row. Am assume it is possible and just need a bit of help.

```
r_ingredients_wtht_tags = []
    for link in r_links:
        r = requests.get(link)
        # print(r.status_code)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
            r_name = soup.find('h1', {'itemprop': 'name'}).text.replace('recipe', '')
            r_prep_time = soup.select('li.recipe-meta-tag')[1].text
            r_ingrdnts_with_tags = soup.select('span[itemprop="ingredients"]')

            for r_ingrdnts in r_ingrdnts_with_tags:  # Remove span tags from list items
                r_ingredients_wtht_tags.append(r_ingrdnts.text)
            # print(r_ingredients_wtht_tags)
            # exit()
            r_image_src = soup.find('img', {'itemprop': 'image'}).get('src')
            r_image_url = 'https://website.com' + r_image_src # dummy website
            r_url = link

            # Download the recipe image
            print('Downloading image %s...' % (r_image_url))
            rec_image = requests.get(r_image_url)
            rec_image.raise_for_status()  # Will raise an exception if above request failed.

            # Create image folder to store current recipe image
            os.makedirs('recipe' + str(image_fold_count), exist_ok=True)

            # Save recipe image
            imageFile = open(os.path.join('recipe' + str(image_fold_count), os.path.basename(r_image_url)), 'wb')
            for chunk in rec_image.iter_content(100000):
                imageFile.write(chunk)
            imageFile.close()

            # write to csv file. NOTE TO SELF: MOVE THIS TO ITS OWN FUNCTION
            fileWriter.writerow(zip(r_name, r_prep_time, r_ingredients_wtht_tags, r_url +"\n"))

            image_fold_count += 1  # Increment recipe folder counter
```

Comment: The "why isn't this code working" close-reason applies perfectly here, so I am going to quote it before the question is closed: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: why do you use `zip()` to write in csv ? you should use list `[r_name, r_prep_time, r_ingredients_wtht_tags, r_url +"\n"]`

Comment: why do you add `"\n"` to `r_url` ? `csv` will add `\n` automatically at the end of row.

Comment: if `r_ingredients_wtht_tags` is a list and you want all elements in separated cells then create list this way `[r_name, r_prep_time] +  r_ingredients_wtht_tags + [r_url]`

Comment: @furas r_ingredients_wtht_tags is a list. So you are saying I generate another list of all the four items and write that as a row. Didn't cross my mind but let me try it. '\n' was an attempt to add a new line after each item in r_ingredients_wtht_tags. Should not even be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `r_ingredients_wtht_tags` is a list and you want all four elements in one row but in separated cells then you can create list in this way

```
row = [r_name, r_prep_time, r_ingredients_wtht_tags, r_url]
```

or convert `r_ingredients_wtht_tags` into string with some separator.
You can use event `,` and `csv` will put this into `" "` automatically.

```
ingredients = ",".join(r_ingredients_wtht_tags)
row = [r_name, r_prep_time, ingredients, r_url]
```

If every ingredient has to be in separated cell the you can do

```
row = [r_name, r_prep_time] + r_ingredients_wtht_tags + [r_url]
```

And write it in `csv` without `zip()` (and without `"\n"` - `csv` will add it at the end of row)

```
fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hi @furas. Thanks for your help. Am able to write in a single row but the first list is repeated for all the rows in the csv. Am looking to see if it is my code logic even though the writer object is inside a for loop.

Comment: use `print()` to display variables and which part of code is executed. It helps to find problem.

Comment: Fixed the repeating issues. I had declared the empty list outside the loop. Silly me. Thanks for your help. Your fix above worked.

Comment: Side note: Am on windows and passing newline='' into the open function while creating the writer object removes the new line added into the csv file after each row.

Comment: Just tried to vote for your helpful answer but I cannot since am still a newbie here. Much appreciated though.

Comment: maybe you need more points or maybe you have to wait 30 minutes - I don't remeber.